# Magento cart page shifting content left in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, magento

When someone using IE visits my sire and adds an item to the cart, they're taken to the cart page, all is well there.

But in IE, the cart content shifts all the way to the right for some reason, and I can't figure out why :-(

starnursery.com

In IE, if you add a product to the cart, you'll see what I mean.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Thanks!!!
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a css problem. Your main column is set to be narrower than the content on the page and IE is centering the content as if it was that wide with the overflow to the right. Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.checkout-cart-index #content #midcol {width: 890px;}
```

Comment: Thanks Jasuten!!!  Looks a lot better now :-)